# Recurrence equation for dynamic programming

Tags: dynamic-programming

I have a situation that is really similar to the knapsack problem but I just want to confirm that my recurrence equation is the same as the knapsack problem.

We have a maximum of M dollars to invest. We have N different investments which each one have a cost m(i) and a profit g(i). We want to find the recurrence equation for maximize the profit.

here is my answer :

```
     g(i,j) = max{g(i-1,j), g_i + (i-1,j-m_i)}      if j-m_i >= 0

              g(i-1,j)                              if j-m_i < 0
```

I hope my explanation are clear.

Thank you and have a nice day!

Bobby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recurrence equation is correct. The problem is same as the traditional knapsack problem. Actually you can make some optimization on space complexity. Here is the C++ code.

```
int dp[M + 10];
int DP{
    memset(dp, 0, sizeof(dp));
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for(int j = M; j >= m[i]; --j) // pay attention
            dp[j] = max(dp[j], dp[j - m[i]] + g[i]);
    int ret = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= M; ++i) ret = max(ret, dp[i]);
    return ret;
}
```